# Create topic in KafkaContainer for Integration Test

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, spring-integration, spock, testcontainers

I'm trying to create a topic in my KafkaContainer using `@ServiceConnection` - when running the application I get an error message when I'm trying to produce to the topic saying `Topic myTopic not present in metadata after 1000 ms.`

Also seeing: `Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected`
Which makes me think my `@ServiceConnection` isn't setup correctly.

I am using the `@Testcontainers` to spin up an SFTP instance, to grab the mounted file. That file then goes through integration flows, until it is produced onto the topic.

Code:

```
@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class FullIntegrationTest extends Specification {

    @Bean
    @ServiceConnection
    KafkaContainer kafkaContainer() {
        return new KafkaContainer(DockerImageName.parse('confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest'))
                .withEnv("TOPIC_AUTO_CREATE", "true")
    }
```

I can provide more information as needed. If this is not the correct way of configuring the topics I was wondering if someone can provide me with an example. I have also been following this [article](https://medium.com/@TimvanBaarsen/programmatically-create-kafka-topics-using-spring-kafka-8db5925ed2b1), but still couldn't get it configure the new topic.

EDIT: application-test.properties

```
spring.kafka.properties.schema.registry.url                  = mock://notused
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers                               = localhost:9092
spring.kafka.properties.sasl.mechanism                       = ""
spring.kafka.properties.security.protocol                    = PLAINTEXT
spring.kafka.properties.basic.auth.credentials.source        = ""

spring.kafka.properties.schema.registry.basic.auth.user.info = ""
spring.kafka.properties.sasl.jaas.config                     = ""
```

Comment: You need to consult with that `confluentinc/cp-kafka` Docker image vendor to determine what ENV vars they support for your requirements. It is too much here: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/docker/config-reference.html#confluent-ak-configuration, but doesn't look like they mention props you show in the question...

Comment: I'm also not seeing anything about topic creation in that documentation, do you think I can manually setup some configuration like the article I linked above? I just feel like there should be a pretty straight forward way of doing this. @ArtemBilan

Comment: See if just `TOPIC_AUTO_CREATE` is enough.

Comment: @ArtemBilan - Attempted that, now I am seeing it is having trouble connecting to the broker, so my configuration in my `application-test.properties` may not be setup correctly for `@ServiceConnection` I will edit question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove the `@ServiceConnection` and added Zookeeper, with the env variables.

```
    @Shared
    static final KafkaContainer kafkaContainer = new KafkaContainer(DockerImageName.parse('confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest'))
            .withEmbeddedZookeeper()
            .withEnv("KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE", "true")
            .withEnv("KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS", Constants.KAFKA_TOPIC + ":1:1")

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void dynamicProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers", () -> kafkaContainer.getBootstrapServers())
        registry.add("engage.server", () -> sftpDockerContainer.getServiceHost("sftp_server", 22))
        registry.add("engage.port", () -> sftpDockerContainer.getServicePort("sftp_server", 22))
    }
```